# iOS - discovering roving network's RN-42 BTLE chip

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am working on a project where I have to discover a bluetooth chip provided by Roving Networks - [RN-42](http://www.rovingnetworks.com/Apple_iOS_Support). The development kit come with an ios application which shows how to communicate with the chip but first we have to connect/pair (manually) with the chip using iOS settings. It uses EAAccessory Framework and works fine. 
What I want is to discover the bluetooth chip from my application and then connect/pair with it automatically but I cannot find a way on how to do that. I am using CoreBluetooth framework to discovery the chip but nothing comes up. Here is how I try to scann for BT devices using CBCentralManager

```
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
                                            options:nil];
```

But I don't get anything back in the callback.

Thanks

Comment: RN-42 is a Bluetooth Low energy capable device right? How Mikko's answer is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoreBluetooth framework only allows you to discover Bluetooth LE capable devices, and does not show classical Bluetooth (BT3.0 and older) devices at all.

Apple had API calls to discover classical Bluetooth devices, but I think they have been removed lately.

You need a product like this in order to do in App pairing and connections:
http://www.bluegiga.com/BLE113_Bluetooth_Smart_module

Comment: As Mikko says, the Roving Networks chip is an MFi accessory (from their page: "All products designed to connect to iPhone's, iPod's and iPad's including those that incorporate the Roving Bluetooth APL module must be registered and approved with Apple's Made for iPod (MFi) program."). Core Bluetooth is for non-MFi Bluetooth LE connections, so you're not going to see them using that framework.

Comment: This really sucks - what are the options for inexpensive hobbyist interfacing? Seems like WiFi only, or stick with Android.